# Edge Probability of Erdos Renyi random graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Given a graph $G(n,p)$ modeled by random graph model, is there any way to find $p$ when number of nodes $n$, number of edges $m$, degrees associated with each node and the total degree, probability that the graph is connected is all available.

Specifically, can you look at a graph and find the edge probability?

Comment: You wouldn't *know* for sure, but you could come up with a statistical estimator $\hat{p}$ for it based on the available data

Comment: Is there a particular way to do that?

Comment: One way I can think of is simply to use the sample mean: $\widehat{p} = m / \binom{n}{2}$. There are probably other estimators, but I'm not too familiar.

Comment: In the question's first paragraph, the probability that the graph is connected is available. That with $n$ should be enough to determine $p$. But in the second paragraph, you only look at the graph, so you have just that one sample point from the space of graphs. In particular, you don't have the probability of connectedness. In this case, you surely can't determine $p$.